# XPath: How to save the return of a function in a variable?

Tags: xml, xpath, oxygenxml

Is it possible to save each item in the  elements in a xpath variable to use this value in same expression? The XPath expression have to be in one line. My goal is to transform the duration in milliseconds, in one expression.

**XML**

```
<pt:transcript
            xmlns:pt="https://purl.org/net/hbuschme/teaching/2019ws-infostruk/podcast-transcript/0.1"
            version="0.1">
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" start="00:00:43.101" end="00:00:49.300">Hallo und herzlich willkommen zu Forschergeist, dem Podcast des Stifterverbands für die deutsche Wissenschaft.</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" start="00:00:49.301" end="00:00:57.600">Mein Name ist Tim Pritlove und ich begrüße alle zu Ausgabe Nummer 72 hier in unserer Gesprächsreihe rund um Wissenschaft,</pt:segment>
            <pt:segment contributor="timpritlove" start="00:00:57.601" end="00:01:04.300">wissenschaftliche Fragen, manchmal geht es um Wissenschaft, manchmal geht es auch um die Metafragen der Wissenschaft.</pt:segment>
</pt:transcript>
```

**XPath**

`fn:analyze-string(/pt:transcript/pt:segment[1]/@start, "[0-9][0-9]")`

**Result**

```
Element='<analyze-string-result xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
   <match>00</match>
   <non-match>:</non-match>
   <match>00</match>
   <non-match>:</non-match>
   <match>43</match>
   <non-match>.</non-match>
   <match>10</match>
   <non-match>1</non-match>
</analyze-string-result>'
```

Comment: I'm not exactly clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you update the question with an example of the desired output, or clarify: are you trying to calculate the difference between `@start` and `@end` in milliseconds? Also, are you able to use XPath 2.0 or 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

From XPath 3.0 you can do

```
let $x := analyze-string(....)
return (some expression that references $x)
```